# Rearranging Excel Cell based on Value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm facing problem to rearrange a huge data based on cell value. 
Example: Currently I have an excel file like below image.

Current Excel file
[image: Current Excel file]

> Mr. Ajith | Customer ID: 119982928 | Location: Mumbai, India |
>   Profession: Businessman | Birth Date: 12 July, 1989 | Type: Regular |
>   Acc No: Not Known | Tel. No: Not Available
>
> Mr. Sumon | Customer ID: 119934534 | Profession: Businessman | Type:
>   Regular | Acc No: Not Known | Mobile: 1234567819
>
> Mr. Arafat | Customer ID: 119886140 | Mobile: 678868 | Qualification:
>   M. Sc | Spouse: Not Avaialbel
>
> Mr. Ashok | Customer ID: 119837746 | Birth Date: 12 July, 1989 | Last
>   Trans: February 16, 2018
>
> Mr. Nirmol  | Customer ID: 119789352 | Address: Khayerpara, Dhaka |
>   Telephone: 13344234 | Child: Mr. Subeer

I tried to make this file like below. but, failed several times. I tried to extract text but as there is a huge Data. I'm confused how to do it.

I need this file
[image]

Currently, I'm doing it manually after moving each cell :(
Is there any Vba code or formula to rearrange all data based on their value?

Comment: ... and as an added bonus we get to retype all of the sample data as well!

Comment: Text to Columns with an Index/Match? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It looks like all your data uses ":" to separate info from info type (CustomerID,Location, etc.). Check formulas FIND and MID. You can create a formula to find the position of the ":" and then extract the text after ":"

Comment: I tried Index Match..but, main problem is every row has many different data..so, when I try with Index match, I missed many cells :(

Comment: @Jeeped, I'm really sorry for that. That wasn't my intention dear. I just edited my question. plz, have a look.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, I tried using Kotools "Combine" Function. then, used "Extract Text" function also. But, the main problem is some different data contains every row. That's why I can't solve this. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sub procedure works with two variant arrays.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro3()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, nr As Long
    Dim tmp As Variant, arr As Variant, hdr As Variant, vals As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet4")
        tmp = .Cells(1, "A").CurrentRegion
        ReDim vals(LBound(tmp, 1) To UBound(tmp, 1), LBound(tmp, 2) To UBound(tmp, 2))
        nr = UBound(tmp, 1) + 2

        For i = LBound(tmp, 1) To UBound(tmp, 1)
            vals(i, 1) = tmp(i, 1)
            For j = LBound(tmp, 2) + 1 To UBound(tmp, 2)
                If CBool(InStr(1, tmp(i, j), Chr(58), vbBinaryCompare)) Then
                    arr = Split(tmp(i, j), Chr(58))
                    arr(0) = Trim(arr(0)): arr(1) = Trim(arr(1))
                    hdr = Application.Match(arr(0), .Rows(nr), 0)
                    If IsError(hdr) Then
                        hdr = .Cells(nr, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Column
                        .Cells(nr, hdr) = arr(0)
                        If UBound(vals, 2) < hdr Then
                            ReDim Preserve vals(LBound(tmp, 1) To UBound(tmp, 1), LBound(tmp, 2) To hdr)
                        End If
                    End If
                    vals(i, hdr) = arr(1)
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

        .Cells(nr + 1, "A").Resize(UBound(vals, 1), UBound(vals, 2)) = vals
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Jeeped, LOVE U! You just made my day. It's work! Awesome! I'm your big FAN now!

Answer (score 0):

You may try this formula each cell:

> =IFERROR(INDEX(A1:AZ1,1,MATCH("Customer ID",INDEX(LEFT(A1:AZ1,11),0),0)),"")

Noted: 11 means total number of character in your string

Answer (score 0):

As I said, it looks like the delimiter of your data in this case is always ":", so knowing this, is just play a little bit with Mid, Len and Find.

My formula looks for the position of ":" in the string, and then extract all text after ":"

Check example below (my Excel is in Spanish, notice that)
[image]

My formula (in english) is like this:

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(MID(B1;FIND(":";B1)+1;LEN(B1)-FIND(":";B1)));"")
```

I translated manually, but it should kind of work. IF not, VBA version of this formula is like this (if don't know VBA, forget about it):

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(TRIM(MID(R[-6]C,FIND("":"",R[-6]C)+1,LEN(R[-6]C)-FIND("":"",R[-6]C))),"""")"
```

Anyways, your data is kind of confusing, at least this output, because it mixes data in different columns. For example, Date of birth of Mr. Ashok appears in column of location (column B) when it should be column E

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making one column for each possible category.  Then output the entire table into a single column, with the values separated by | as was done here on Stackoverflow.  Please end that cell with the |, also.

Now we use a combination of mid, len, and find to extract the data.  The formula I used depends on a space after the colon and the final |, as mentioned.

=IFERROR(MID($A2,FIND(B$1&":",$A2)+2+LEN(B$1),-2-LEN(B$1)+FIND("|",$A2,FIND(B$1&":",$A2))-FIND(B$1&":",$A2)),"")

Cheers!

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But Jeedep's formula works Perfectly.

Comment: Hey, that's great.